# Lock back "Files" to the Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I unlock Files from the  Unity launcher.

I don't find a way to lock it back because when I open a new Files window the icon does not appear inside the launcher.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) 64-bit.

Thank you for your help.